# Необъявленный идентификатор, который по идее должен возвращаться функцией. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: c++

Всем здравия, столкнулся с такой вот проблемой. Необходимо было вывести массив, количество элементов которого зависело от того, входили ли числа обрабатываемой строки матрицы в нужный интервал [z,k] [1,100]. Если в строке таких элементов обнаружено не было, то по условию задачи записывать в элемент одномерного массива 0 - нежелательно. то есть количество элементов одномерного массива должно было быть равным количеству строк с попавшими в интервал числами. Пока данный код - это все что я смог придумать:

```
int array_in(mas a, matr b, int n, int m, int z, int k)
{
    int c=-1, u=1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            if((b[i][j]<=k)&&(b[i][j]>=z))
                u=u*b[i][j];
        a[c++]=u;
    }
    return c;
}
```

И позже, при выводе массива (одномер.) на экран, компилятор жалуется на то, что идентификатор "с" не определен, хотя, по идее, он должен был попасть в главную функцию через оператор return.

Вот текст всей программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef int matr[7][5];
typedef int mas[7];
using namespace std;

void matrix_in(matr a, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            a[i][j]=rand()/100-11;
}
int array_in(mas a, matr b, int n, int m, int z, int k)
{
    int c=-1, u=1;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            if((b[i][j]<=k)&&(b[i][j]>=z))
                u=u*b[i][j];
        a[c++]=u;
    }
    return c;
}
void main()
{
    matr A;
    matr B;
    mas X;
    mas Y;
    matrix_in(A, 7, 5);
    matrix_in(B, 7, 5);
    array_in(X, A, 7, 5, 1, 100);
    array_in(Y, B, 7, 5, 1, 100);

    cout<<"Matrix A"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) 
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
                cout<<setw(4)<<A[i][j];
        }

    cout<<"Matrix B"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) 
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
                cout<<setw(4)<<B[i][j];
        }
    cout<<"Array X"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++)
            cout<<setw(4)<<X[i];

    cout<<"Array Y"<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++)
            cout<<setw(4)<<Y[i];
}
```

В общем, у меня возникли трудности лишь с выводом переменной "с" из тела функции "array_in". Насколько я понял, тут какой-то кардинально иной подход требуется. Если у кого-то есть чем поделиться, я буду рад)

Comment: Идентификатор не покидает функцию через `return`. Идентификатор вообще конструкция времени компиляции. Функцию покидает возвращаемое значение. Присвойте его какой-то переменной, и будем вам счастье.

А вообще-то, программировать надо было учиться до зачётной недели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то, что объявленно внутри функции - личное дело самой функции. Назад возвращается не переменная, а только ее значение.

Поэтому, Вам нужно писать где то так

```
int cc = array_in(Y, B, 7, 5, 1, 100); // имя cc взято с головы
//.. тут какой то отдельный код
cout << "c = " << cc;
```

Comment: @KoVadim
Хех, а ларчик просто открывался)) Спасибо огромное!